# How to protect GET methods for .net application if the cookie is stolen

Tags: asp.net, security

How to protect GET methods if the cookie is stolen since Antiforgery Token only protects the POST methods? The web application can return sensitive information via GET method.

I am using .AspNetCore claim based identity. I was trying to use Postman to view the content of the GET method, but I cannot get the it to work.
I assume this is theoretically possible. An authorized user cookie can be hijacked by a man sit in middle right?

The site is secured by SSL and I think the .AspNetCore claim based identity is session based cookie. What are the chances to break in to execute the GET methods and get returns values. How to secure the application?

Comment: Once an attacker can access the victim's cookies, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

**It should never get to that point**

Don't use just a cookie to validate a user. You should use several cookies based on each session, such as the device name or id, the device's IP address, a session ID stored in their browser, potentially something stored in their local data (permanently stored even if cookies are deleted) that validates that particular PC etc. There are plenty of other methods of security a user's identity.

However, if you use a session cookie and nothing else to authenticate a user, then you should probably revise how your application secures its users first. Because if that session cookie is stolen, then it's a bad sign for your user.